# How to modify safely CCLabelBMFont String after first allocation created?

Tags: text, cocos2d-iphone, label

I have a member named _label as an ivar member in class :

```
@interface CCHelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{
  CCLabelBMFont *_label;
}
```

in another codeblock: initializing with this line:

```
_label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Testing " fntFile:fntName];
```

question is this:
if I want to modify its text what Should I do ?
I dont see any method like:

```
[_label setString:@"Well.there is no such a method"];
```

if I do

```
_label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Testing " fntFile:fntName];

_label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Well.there is no such a method"
         fntFile:fntName];
```

is first memory allocation autoreleasing it self ?
is it safe to recall labelWithString method repeately ?
(note:I dont use ARC in test project.and I wont.)

thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `setString` method but it appears to be "private".  The `+labelWithString` method does create an autorelease object and can be used repeatedly.  It looks like it creates a texture, so you would want to create a new texture each time (as opposed to trying to modify it).

In general though, if you want the autoreleased object to stick around, you should `retain` it and `release` it when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

```
[_label setString:@"Well.there is no such a method"];
```

This method exists and you can call it like that. Try it, it works.

The method is not declared in the class but in CCLabelProtocol.